# Request.IsAuthenticated always returning false on Login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, razor

I am using below code to login the user -

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public void Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            WebSecurity.Login(model.EMail, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe);
            return;
        }

        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        return;
    }
```

After he is logged in, in my layout file, I am checking if he is authenticated or not  -

```
    @if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
         <div>not authenticated</div>
    }

    @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
         <div>authenticated</div>
    }
```

But, somehow this is always returning "not authenticated". When I register and then login, this piece of code works fine. Can anyone suggest what can be the issue here?

Register code -

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public void Register(RegisterModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Attempt to register the user
            try
            {
                WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.EMail, model.Password);
                WebSecurity.Login(model.EMail, model.Password);
            }
            catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
            }
        }

        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use WebSecurity class:

```
 @if (!WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
         <div>not authenticated</div>
    }

    @if (WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
         <div>authenticated</div>
    }
```

See [here (**Adding Security and Membership to an ASP.NET Web Pages (Razor) Site**)](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/security/16-adding-security-and-membership)

or you can try:

```
@if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
 // user is logged in
}
else
{
 // user is not loggged in
}
```

### UPDATE:

and in login action check this way if login was successful:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public void Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.EMail, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
    {
     // login successful
    }
    else
    {
     // login failed
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it but it is not working. What I am not sure why I get it correctly on register and not on login.

Comment: on Register what you get and what you got on login?

Comment: authenticated after Register and not authenticated after login. Essentially I am using the same statement to login.

WebSecurity.Login(model.EMail, model.Password);

Comment: Request.IsAuthenticated itself checks User.Identity.IsAuthenticated, so the result is going to be the same.

Comment: are you sure login is successfull??

Comment: i used to check this way: ``if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))``  this will return true if login successful

Comment: Oh, no it's not. I am not sure how that makes a difference. But I changed it like you said and it works now.

Comment: you are actually doing wrong ``WebSecurity.Login()`` returns `bool` `true` or ``false`` that login was successful or not

Answer (score 4):

Just Add the following code in your Web.config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/_Login/Login" timeout="30" />
</authentication>
```

and

```
<modules>
  <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
  <add name="FormsAuthentication" type="System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule" />
</modules>
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

this MSDN link may help. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx

```
if (Membership.ValidateUser(userName.Text, password.Text))
{
    if (Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] != null)
    {
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(userName.Text, false);
    }
    else
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName.Text, false);
    }
}
else
{
    Response.Write("Invalid UserID and Password");
}
```